# how can i make a conditional rendering to a result from filter method? react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uisearchbar, conditional-rendering

i have a father component that passes to a son component all the assets available for rent and render it...
 at the same component i have a search-bar that should make the search much easier and i want that as a result of the input,  render the specific card(s) that matches the search..
if nothing inserted in the search bar it renders all the assets , if the user type the name of the asset and it matches one or many of the assets it will render the matching asset(s).

here's my code..

```
class AllAssets extends Component {

  state = {
    cards: [],
    searchField: ''
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = await cardService.getAllCards();
    if (data.length > 0) this.setState({ cards: data });
  }

  addToFavorites = (cardId, userId) => {
    saveToFavorites(cardId, userId)
    toast.error("The asset was added to your favorites.")
  }

  render() {

    const { cards, searchField } = this.state;
    const user = getCurrentUser();

    const filteredAssets = cards.filter(card => (
      card.assetName.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())

    ))
    console.log(filteredAssets);

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <SearchBox placeholder={"Enter asset name..."}
          handleChange={(e) => this.setState({ searchField: e.target.value })}
        />
        <PageHeader>Assets available for rent</PageHeader>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12 mt-4">
            {cards.length > 0 && <p>you can also add specific assets to your favorites and get back to them later...</p>}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {cards.filteredAssets === true ? cards.map(card => <CardPublic addToFavorites={this.addToFavorites} card={filteredAssets} user={user} key={card._id} />) :
            cards.map(card => <CardPublic addToFavorites={this.addToFavorites} card={card} user={user} key={card._id} />)
          }
        </div>
      </div >
    );
  }
}

export default AllAssets;
```

i tried with the ternary operator but that dosen't work..

```
 {cards.filteredAssets === true ? cards.map(card => <CardPublic addToFavorites={this.addToFavorites} card={filteredAssets} user={user} key={card._id} />)
 : cards.map(card => <CardPublic addToFavorites={this.addToFavorites} card={card} user={user} key={card._id} />)
          }
```

in the console the results are just fine..
thank you very much in advance...

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as `cards.filteredAssets` in your code. There's the `cards` array and then there's the `filteredAssets` array (that is the result of a filtering function on the `cards` array). So, `cards.filteredAssets` doesn't exist, so it is falsy (FALSE), never TRUE.

Using the *strict equality operator* (`===`) `filteredAssets` will never equal `true`. `filterdAssets` is an `Array`, `true` is a `Boolean`. The types aren't the same, so the equality will say "not equal" at the first step ([ECMAScript 2022 specification 7.2.16](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isstrictlyequal))

You could use

```
!!filteredAssets.length === true
```

(Note on why `!!filteredAssets.length` works, but simply `!!filteredAssets` would not work:

- the first `!` coerces the value to be a `Boolean` (truthy -> FALSE, falsy -> TRUE, as `!` is logical negation), the second `!` just negates the `Boolean` (that is negated), thus yielding the truthy -> TRUE, falsey -> FALSE final result;
- as `[]` is truthy, simply `!!filteredAssets` would always return TRUE

```js
const arr = []
console.log("arr:", arr, !!arr)
```

)

or just simply

```
filteredAssets.length // 0 length is falsy (FALSE), any other length is truthy (TRUE)
```

or you could just simply handle this whole thing when you create the `filteredAssets` array (so, if the length of the result of the `filter` function is 0, then you should just make it equal to `cards`).

### BUT

- If possible, do the whole thing with functional components (not class components), use the hooks (`useState`, `useEffect`, etc.) and you'll get a much nicer looking component.
- Please, don't call components "father" and "son"; the accepted naming convention says they are "parent" (even "grandparent", if needed) and "child" (yes, "grandchild"; simply put: people won't understand what you're talking about if you don't communicate with the widely accepted terms.)

## EDIT

After a comment from OP, I add this snippet:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

// custom hook for mocking API data
const useUsersApi = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);

  // only runs once
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        setResponse(() => json.map(({id, name, username, email}) => ({id, name, username, email})))
      })
  }, []);

  return response;
};

const SearchBar = ({ onSearch }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Search by name:
      <input
        type="text"
        onInput={(e) => onSearch(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

const UserCard = ({ userData }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="card"
    >
      <h3>{userData.name}</h3>
      <ul>
        {
          Object.entries(userData).map(([key, val]) => {
            return (
              <li
                key={key}
              >
                {key}: {val}
              </li>
            )
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const users = useUsersApi()
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState('')
  const [filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers] = useState([])

  const onSearchInput = (val) => {
    setSearchString(() => val)
  }
  
  const filterUsersByName = (s) => {
    return users.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().indexOf(s.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredUsers(() => filterUsersByName(searchString))
  }, [searchString, users])
 
  return (
    <div
      className="container"
    >
      <SearchBar
        onSearch={onSearchInput}
      />
      {
        filteredUsers.map(user => {
          return (
            <UserCard
              userData={user}
              key={user.id}
            />
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.card {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I hope this snippet helps you more: I used functional components with hooks to do case-insensitive filtering on fictional users' names.

Comment: hey greg, thanks for your kind answer but actually it's not solving my problem.. can you be more specific and try to help more? i can see you have a great knowledge

Comment: @juniorkim I added a snippet that does what you described (at least how I understood) :)